# Question about Key lookups

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, ssis, ssrs

I have a table with 100 columns. The Primary key and clustered index are on the column **Id** - IX01_Id. I have a non-clustered index on **Col2** - IX02_Col2.

I have 3 stored procedures that return the following columns from this table:

```
Sp1: Col2 to Col10
Sp2: Col8 to Col15 plus Col2
Sp3: Col13 to Col21 plus Col2

For Sp1, we're doing a key lookup to get col3 to col10
For sp2, we're doing a key lookup to get col8 to col15
For sp3, we're doing a key lookup to get col13 to col21
```

Does the key lookup in the execution plan make IX02_Col2 useless since it has to do a clustered index scan on the main table while doing the key lookup?

My co-worker suggested that we include col3 through col21 in the index IX02_Col2. Won't it make the index table too large? What are the consequences of adding too many included columns?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of an index with included columns as a clustered index, with the key columns as the clustering key and the included columns as the other columns in the table.

No, the index will not be useless. SQL Server can seek and based on that seek all the data is in the index - no lookups. But the fatter the index, the fewer pages fits on a page.

One important question here is if the table has a clustered index and on what column. If the clustered index is on the id column, then you essentially have your index already - having all the columns in the table as "included columns" (see my analogy above). Apparently, this isn't the case, since you wouldn't have the lookups in your plans. I.e., is your clustered index on the right column(s) is a very first question to ask your self.

Another factor is how selective your queries are. Say that they all return 1 row. Then you won't see much difference (at all) from havine 1 included column to having 20 includes columns. But as selectivity goes down, the fewer rows fit per page and the more pages have to be read.

And then you of course also have the aspect of index overhead. Not only disk storage, which should be obvious. But I'm thinking about overhead when you modify data, and this can be substantial.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Tibor! I missed a few points in my question. I updated my question to reflect what I'm looking for. Thank you for your time!

Comment: So I assume your procedures uses Col2 in the WHERE clause. How selective are those queries? If very selective, then covering won't buy you much. If not selective, then it might be worth the cost. I.e., how much do those lookups really cost you. then is is a matter of if you want that overhead and if you want one index per query or one that covers all three queries. The more tailored index to the query, the more efficient (the narrower).

Comment: Each of the procedures join to other tables and Col2 is used to join on some of those tables. Each stored procedure returns more than 500 rows. This table is frequently updated as well.

Comment: I see. In the end it is up to you to test the various options and the efficiency of each. The current index structure, one index that covers all queries or one covering index per query.  And of course weigh in the overhead.